# UIImageView Animation Playground

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimageview, swift-playground

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import XCPlayground

//main window
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 320))
//array of images
let animationPictures: [UIImage] =
[
        UIImage(named: "first.png")!,
        UIImage(named: "second.png")!
]
var animationBkg = UIImageView()
animationBkg.animationImages = animationPictures;
animationBkg.animationDuration = 0.5
animationBkg.startAnimating()
```

Here is the code I currently have. the goal is to have these two images playing one after another as an animation, but it isn't working. In the preview of my code, all it has is a black square.

Comment: Have you tried adding `import XCPlayground; XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true`?

Comment: I updated the code

Comment: I added in the things you said and it threw an error on that second line of code

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

```
let animationPictures: [UIImage] =
[
        UIImage(named: "first.png")!,
        UIImage(named: "second.png")!
]
//animation
var animationView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(480), height: CGFloat(320)))
animationView.animationImages = animationPictures
animationView.animationDuration = 1.5
animationView.animationRepeatCount = 0
animationView.startAnimating()
view.addSubview(animationView)
```

I found a solution to my own problem. Thanks for the help